# Where is the Rendering Done

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rendering

This may be a silly question.

I have a canvas and I load an image to it.

Before I do so I use JavaScript to brighten the image by going through the image data pixels and adjusting the RGB values.

Now, being JS it will do this on client-side.  But when I update the Canvas will this also be done on Client-Side or will the whole rendering be done on the Server?

Like I said this could be a dumb question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas, being a html element drawn into via javascript, is entirely handled by the client. Only the original image, the html site and the js itself will be obtained from the server (but the image itself will also never be rendered by the server)

Comment: Many thanks. Logic told me so but I had the ask the question in case I was totally thick :). Thank you..